# Learning to create custom Silverlight Components

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

Is there a place on the net where I would be able to learn to create custom components for silverlight. I'm wondering how I would begin to learn to create charts for specific purposes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many online resources for Silverlight development. Just some are...

[Silveright Official Website](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/)

[SilverlightTV - Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV)

[Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Home&ProjectName=silverlight)

[PDC 2010](http://player.microsoftpdc.com/session)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look at charting controls download and view the silverlight toolkit. 
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/
The source code is under ms public license so you can do whatever you want with it :)

For Silverlight starters check out the silverlight 4 starter kit: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/22/silverlight-4-training-kit.aspx